# Android: How to draw objects onto the screen based on GPS and Gyroscope

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer, augmented-reality

I've been working on an augmented reality application for my university that places a POI button onto each building when looking through a camera preview. I am supposed to program it from scratch, without using something like Layar or Wikitude. 
I have all of the information from the various sensors I think are necessary like the accelerometer, gyroscope, GPS, and compass but, I haven't been able to figure out exactly how I can draw objects to a specific location on the screen and have them move correctly. I'm wondering if anybody here has any experience with this, I assume some Linear Algebra is involved but I can't completely wrap my mind around what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand the general problem, think of it as two steps:

1. combine all those sensor values to tell you where the camera is (GPS), where it is looking (orientation derived from accelerometers and compass: Android should already have something to combine these into one 3D orientation value), and how much of the world you can see (the field of view of the camera -- you need to figure this out!)
2. set up the corresponding 3D graphics rendering system, and then use those values to position you "virtual 3D camera" in the world at the same location and orientation as your phone.

Once you have that, you simply render the 3D graphics (you labels) at their locations in the world and they should appear correctly.

Since you just want to draw labels, you can simplify a lot (e.g., instead of rendering 3D graphics, you could just use the 3D projection to figure out the screen location of each label, and then render the label using normal 2D rendering).

I would suggest using a Euclidean coordinate system for your POIs and camera (convert LLA to UTM, for example, which is in meters).  It makes a lot of things easier.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll spend the next few days designing that and googling euclidean, lla and utm haha. Thanks, I didn't think of it like a virtual 3d camera. hmmm. and thank you!